# How can I find logstash error logs on elastic.co?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

On a self-hosted ELK environment I am aware of how to see errors in the Logstash pipeline to detect log records being thrown away.

But how can I find these errors on a ELK environment hosted by elastic.co?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Logstash in the elastic cloud service hosted by [elastic.co](https://elastic.co), only elasticsearch and kibana instances are available.

If you need logstash in your deployment you will need to host it elsewhere, on-premises or other cloud services, and [configure your instance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/connecting-to-cloud.html) to ship data to your cloud service.

Comment: Thx for the answer . Does it mean there is no way to understand why some logs might be discarded? I know from self-hosted environments that the logstash log can tell you exactly that.